# Convert yyyy-mm-dd to yyyy-ww in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to to convert `yyyy-mm-dd` into `yyyy-ww`.

How is this achieved for the following dataframe:

```
dates = {'date': ['2015-02-04','2016-03-05']}

df = pd.DataFrame(dates, columns=['date'])

print(df)
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I've tried using

```
YW = pd.to_datetime(df, format='%Y%W')
```

However without luck.

Comment: Can you show reproducible code.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) working with columns called `year`, `month` and `day` for datetimes and add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for custom format:

```
YW = pd.to_datetime(df).dt.strftime('%Y%W')
print (YW)
0    201505
1    201609
dtype: object
```

If possible another columns filter only necessary by list:

```
YW = pd.to_datetime(df[['year','month','day']]).dt.strftime('%Y%W')
```

EDIT:

```
YW = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%Y%W')
print (YW)
0    201505
1    201609
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you very much - got it to work before your edit, but you definitely got me there.